# Is $\exp \left(-\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{(x_i - y_i)^2}{s_i^2} \right) $ analytic in $\mathbf{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analyticity

I would like to know whether the following statement is true.

**Conjecture**: For all $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $s_1>0,\ldots,s_d>0$, $f_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}) := \exp \left(-\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{(x_i - y_i)^2}{s_i^2} \right) $ is analytic in $\mathbf{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Apology if this is a very well known fact. I am not working in this area.

If it is true, could you please give me a reference? If this is not known, could you please let me know how I might show it? So far, I have been trying to show it by using Proposition 2.2.10 in [A Primer of Real Analytic Functions](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9780817642648) which gives a condition on the partial derivatives for a function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ to be analytic. I have not yet succeeded.

Another thing I notice is that if $d=1$, then $f_y(x) = \exp\left( -(x-y)^2/s^2\right)$ is known as a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function). A Gaussian function is known to be analytic. In our case, we have a product $d$ Gaussian functions. That is, $f_\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x})$ is separately analytic on each coordinate of $\mathbf{x}$. I would like to know if it is jointly analytic in $\mathbf{x}$.

Thanks. (This is not a homework question.)

Comment: Compositions of real analytic functions are real analytic. You are composing the exponential function with a polynomial, so yes, it's real analytic.

Comment: I start to see. Is it correct that you see $-\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{(x_i - y_i)^2}{s_i^2}$ as a multivariate polynomial in $x_1,\ldots, x_d$ and that it is known to be analytic on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly a polynomial. The fact that a polynomial is real-analytic is almost self-proving. After all, what is a polynomial?